# Clusterize (group) array of strings

Tags: perl

I need to group array of strings following way (merge same strings nearby)

```
Input          | Output
---------------+--------------------
[              | [
    'a'        |    'a (x3)',
    'a'        |    'b',
    'a'        |    'c (x2)'
    'b'        |    'd'
    'c'        |    'c'
    'c'        |    'x'
    'd'        | ]
    'c'        |
    'x'        |
]              |
---------------+--------------------
```

How to do that ?

I wrote this code

```
sub str_minus_multiplier {
    my ( $str ) = @_;
    $str =~ s/\(x(\d+)\)//;
    return $str;
}

sub str_add_multiplier {
    my ( $str, $num ) = @_;
    $num = 1 if !defined $num;
    if ( my $n = str_has_multiplier($str) ) {
        $str = str_minus_multiplier($str);
        my $new_m = $n+$num;
        $str.= '(x'.$new_m.')';
    } else {
        $str.= ' (x2)';
    }
    return $str;
}

sub fold_list {
    my ( @x ) = @_;
    for my $i (0 .. $#x-1) {

        my $j = 1;
        while ( str_minus_multiplier($x[$i]) eq $x[$i+$j] ) {
            $x[$i] = str_add_multiplier($x[$i]);
            $j++;
        }
        splice(@x, $i+1, $j-1) if ( $j > 1 );
    }
    return @x;
}
```

But it's not working as expected, output of `fold_list()` is

```
[
          'a (x2)',
          'a',
          'b',
          'c (x2)',
          'd',
          'c',
          'x',
          ' (x2)'
        ];
```

I guess that problem is in `str_minus_multiplier($x[$i]) eq $x[$i+$j]` comparision, after splice one value in comparision is `undef`. How to avoid that ?

Comment: Put them in a Hashmap where the key is the letter and the value is the time it appears then just print key value with where value > 1 else print only the key.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show us the code you already have. The easiest approach is to walk through the array and remember the last string and the current count and to output the last string+count whenever the last string is not equal to the current string.

Comment: I would do something like `my $count = 0; my $last_string; @filtered_list = map { $last_string = $_; if( $last_string ne $_ ) { "$last_string x $count" } else { $count++; (); } @original_list; push @filtered_list, "$last x $count";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be overcomplicating the problem. Essentially, this is a variant of [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

The idea is to walk through the list and increment a counter at each character to compute how long the "run" is, or how many subsequent characters are equal to the current character. Once you've found the length, add it to the result in the appropriate format and skip all of the elements you just squashed together.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a = split //, "aaabccdcx";
my @rle;

for (my $i = 0; $i < @a;) {
    my $j = 1;

    while ($i + $j < @a && $a[$i+$j] eq $a[$i]) {
        $j++;
    }

    push @rle, $a[$i] . ($j > 1 ? " (x$j)" : "");
    $i += $j;
}

print Dumper \@rle;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'a (x3)',
          'b',
          'c (x2)',
          'd',
          'c',
          'x'
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways of doing this, I have:

```
$ cat file1
'a'
'a'
'a'
'b'
'c'
'c'
'd'
'x'

$ perl -ne 'END{for(sort keys %count){if($count{$_}>1){ print "$_ \(x$count{$_}\)\n";} else{print "$_\n";}}} chomp; $count{$_}++;' file1
'a' (x3)
'b'
'c' (x2)
'd'
'x'
```

Comment: This loses the original order of the input strings

Comment: The OP's sample input has a 'c' between the 'd' and the 'x' at the end of the list which needs to be kept separate. This code includes it with the two 'c's that appear earlier in the list.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want. It's longer than the other answers but (hopefully) less cryptic.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $string = 'aaabccdcx';

my $prev = '';
my $count;
my @out;

for (split //, $string) {
  if ($_ eq $prev) {
    $count++;
  } else {
    push @out, $prev . ($count > 1 ? " (x$count)" : '') if $count;
    $count = 1;
    $prev = $_;
  }
}

push @out, $prev . ($count > 1 ? " (x$count)" : '');

print Dumper \@out;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl - using backreference

```
$ echo "aaabccdcx"| perl -nle ' while( /(.)(\1*)/g ) { $t=length("$1$2"); print "$1 -> ",$t> 1? "x(".$t.")" : "" } '
a -> x(3)
b ->
c -> x(2)
d ->
c ->
x ->
$
```

standalone

```
$  perl -le ' $str="aaabccdcx"; while($str=~/(.)(\1*)/g ) { $t=length("$1$2"); print "$1 -> ",$t> 1? "x(".$t.")" : "" } '
a -> x(3)
b ->
c -> x(2)
d ->
c ->
x ->
$
```